# We seem to be under a college football spam attack

Tags: support, spam

Every few minutes we're getting spam questions for a variety of college football live streaming sites.

I think they're probably being added manually, but I'm no expert.

I'm flagging as I see them, but they have not yet abated. Can someone with more power see if there's an IP address block that needs to be created?

Comment: Taking a look into it. Related [Livestream sports spam](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2448/88163)

Comment: Are the post being reported in Charcoal? Or are they caught by SD? Looking at the recent SD reports, the most active day seems to be with five spam posts: https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?room=11540&q=webapps.stackexchange.com